# storing repeating data in SharePoint list

Tags: json, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath2010, repeat

We have a requirement of storing the repeating data (multiple rows) in the SharePoint list. 
The requirement is to store multiple set/structure of repeating data like 
Address 1 to Address 5 
Phone 1 to Phone 5
City 1 to City 5 
State 1 to State 5

the requirement is to have it extendable so we can add additional fields in repeating tables (similar to info-path form).

We are using custom page in SharePoint for data entry and wanted to check what is best way to store the data. We wanted to use Jquery table to edit/display the data.   We were contemplating storing it in XML or JSON instead of creating lists for each such types.Is Storing as JSON object/text/XML in same list advisable and/or used in design?

Answer (score 0):

If the user isn't going to have any direct view on to the list where the data is being stored, I would recommend making up some form of structure that works for you. The below allows you to give the user a basic view of data that is common accross all items and then if they want more info create a custom page to display the rest of the information.

We normally will store data we know every item will have in an individual field so Address 1 <- everyone may have this then have another field that is a comments field with some data structure. "Address 2: Spooner Street;Address 3:Gotham;" <- store this in your comments field and dynamically build a page to display these.

Hope this helps

Truez